# jquery best controls that generated tree

Tags: jquery

ok can someone tell me the best tree view control in jquery? apart from dynatree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [jQuery TreeView plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/treeview).

Answer (score 4):

I am using
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/index.html

it's very well written and allows for quite a bit of programming control. check it out!

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: The nice thing about his one is it supports 2 formats to load the tree. A flat node id and parent format and a node and nested children format.

Answer (score 0):

i use this one: [jQuery treeTable Plugin](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/index.html) because its really simple, lightweight, easy to understand/extend and it looks pretty : >

I used to use [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) which is also good and well documented but i switched over because i found it a bit too heavy for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Best tree control I've seen so far for jQuery ... [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/)